# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404 WrappedWebSocket @ VM222:161

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I have a jetty server and i followed the instructions from https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jetty/jetty-websocket-example/

i defined a `@ServerEndpoint`:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/jsr356toUpper")
public class ToUpper356Socket {

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) {
    System.out.println("WebSocket opened: " + session.getId());
}
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String txt, Session session) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Message received: " + txt);
    session.getBasicRemote().sendText(txt.toUpperCase());
}

@OnClose
public void onClose(CloseReason reason, Session session) {
    System.out.println("Closing a WebSocket due to " + reason.getReasonPhrase());

}
```

}

but i get :

> Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404 WrappedWebSocket @ VM222:161

when I am trying to reach to ws://localhost:8080/jsr356toUpper

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, apparently I used an old jetty plugin

```
   <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
```

instead of

```
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```